# flutter_email_sender doesn't send email

Tags: flutter, dart, pubspec

I just copied the readme file and put it into an example project, Im trying to send a email but it always have the same error.

PlatformException(not_available, No email clients found!, null, null)

There's my code:

```
sendMail() async {

final email = 'email';
    
      final smtpServer = smtpserver('aa@aa.com', 'pwd');
    
      final msg = Message()
        ..from = Address(email)
        ..recipients = ['aaa@aaa.com']
        ..subject = 'this works!'
        ..text = 'something';
    
      String platformResponse;
    
      try {
        await send(msg, smtpServer);
        platformResponse = 'success';
        print(platformResponse);
      } catch (error) {
        print(error);
        platformResponse = error.toString();
      }
    }
```

AndroidManifest.xml, it says that Android v.11 needs some permisions. So i just copy them.

I changed the package and I started to use mailer. It was more easy to use and It has similar use and more documentation.

[Mailer How to use it and configure smtp](https://github.com/taljacobson/flutter_mailer)

I created my own smtp.

Example of smtp:

```
import 'package:mailer/smtp_server.dart'

SmtpServer config_smtp(String username, String password) =>
    SmtpServer('your.smtp.com',username: username,password: password);
```

Comment: What email clients are installed on the device?

Comment: What do you mean of "installed"? you mean if they use "gmail"? in that case i don't use that bc I don't need the 2fa

Comment: The `No email clients found!` error strongly implies that flutter uses an existing email client to send mail and doesn't send mail directly. On the device, what existing app/software is used to send email, if any?

Comment: It doesn't have any. Im putting directly all the information inside de code bc I don't want to use external apps to do that. I mean I want to use flutter_email_sender as a notificator. And thanks for the aclaration

Comment: <permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES" />

Comment: add this and try once again

Answer (score 0):

add this in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest package="com.mycompany.myapp">
  <queries>
   <intent>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
    <data android:scheme="mailto" />
   </intent>
  </queries>
</manifest>
```

check here for [more info](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_email_sender)

Comment: I put this already and I still have same problem

Comment: if ur testing in emulator, please test in real device once.

Comment: final Email email = Email(
    body: "example",
    subject: "title",
    recipients: ['bb@bb.com'],
    cc: ['aa@aa.com'],
    isHTML: false,
  ); use proper email formate

Comment: If u still facing the pbm, thn try url_launcher

Answer (score 0):

May be this package can help you. I am using this package for sending emails `url_launcher: ^6.1.5`. It was quite succesfull every time I used it. So if it is not important what package you should use you can try it out.

Also always recommend to test such things in real device. Sometimes it could not work on emulator

Comment: When using Flutter Web, im running the app in the browser. The app inside a browser can't connect to a random socket, only when using the http protocol (or in some cases ftp). Postgresql doesn't have an http interface, therefore you won't be able to connect to it from Flutter web (or from regular JS web). So I change it into an emulator and it create a smtp to send email